# How do I increase the video memory in VMWare Workstation for OS X 10.12?

Tags: windows, macos, virtual-machine

I'm using VMWare Workstation 12 to run OS X 10.12 from Windows 10 Home. I have an NVidia GeForce GTX 960M with 2 GB dedicated video memory. I don't see a setting in the virtual machine setting that allows me to change the amount of video memory allotted to the guest. If I remember correctly I think I maxed it out at 128 MB during the setup. Can someone help me figure out how to give the guest more video memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this isn't an option on workstation.